# aptana studio 3 path variables

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I need to edit the path variables for a project in Aptana Studio 3 but the edit button is greyed out. 
I mistakenly (unknowingly!) deleted the directories that the PARENT_LOC and WORKSPACE_LOC path variables point to. Now Apatana gives me an error when trying to autosave.
Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried just recreating the directory?

Comment: No. But I don't want the directory in that location anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two locations are automatically set to wherever your project's workspace is located.

To change where the workspace is located you need to set Aptana to prompt you for a workspace location when you start it:

1. In Apatana:
   `Window > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown > Prompt for workspace on startup: Checked`
   You can type `workspaces` in the searchbox and hit `Enter` to get
   there quicker.
   [image: Aptana 3 Workspaces Preferences]
2. Restart Aptana and it will prompt you for where you want the
   workspace located.
3. Choose or create a new location for the workspace.

Comment: Thanks jmohr, this was really helpful. I realised that if I quit Aptana I was able to delete all the remaining workspace files (that were not deleted while Aptana was running) and when I restarted I could just create a new project. However, it still tried to create a workspace in the old location, so your answer helped me correct that.